# Looping a socket connection attempt eventually disconnects the internet connection

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

```
char IP[30] = "127.0.0.1";
char PORT[10] = "1000";

void Connection(HWND hwnd)
{
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    char * ip = "";
    PHOSTENT hostinfo;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 );
    int ConRes, ConRes2;
    char Buffer [20] = "";

    if ( WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData ) == 0 )
    {
        if((hostinfo = gethostbyname(IP)) != NULL)
        {
            ip = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr *)*hostinfo->h_addr_list);
        }   
    }

    InitWSA();

    begin:

    Sleep(1000);
    RemAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RemAdr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(127.0.0.2);
    RemAdr.sin_port = htons (atoi(PORT));
    client = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    switch(connect (client, (struct sockaddr *)&RemAdr,sizeof(RemAdr)))
    {
    case 0:
        WSAAsyncSelect(client,hwnd,RATMSG_SOCKET,FD_READ|FD_CLOSE|FD_CONNECT);
        return;
        break;

    default:
        Sleep(1000);    
        RemAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        RemAdr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
        RemAdr.sin_port = htons (atoi(PORT));
        client = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        ConRes2=connect (client, (struct sockaddr *)&RemAdr,sizeof(RemAdr));
        break;
    }

    switch(ConRes2)
    {
    case 0:
        WSAAsyncSelect(client,hwnd,RATMSG_SOCKET,FD_READ|FD_CLOSE|FD_CONNECT);
        return;
        break;

    default:
        goto begin;
        break;
    }

    return;
}
```

After a few hours of attempting to connect and failing the connection, the user's internet will eventually disconnect until you close the application. What seems to be the problem? I think my code is a little sloppy though, so any helpful tips would be great, would love to learn.

In this I was actually trying to make a way for it to have a "backup" IP address to connect to should the first one fail. So if it can't connect to 127.0.0.1, try 127.0.0.2 next, then back to 127.0.0.1 for exmaple. How can I manage that?

P.S. anything you see in my code that seems like a "bad habit" please point it out so I can learn/fix it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a handle leak. If the first `connect()` fails, you are calling `socket()` to allocate a new `SOCKET` handle and assigning it to the same `client` variable, losing the `SOCKET` you had previously allocated. If the second call to `connect()` fails, your loop calls `socket()` again and assigns it to the same `client` variable again, and again and again, over and over, until `connect()` finally success, if ever.  That is going to waste resources over time. You need to get rid of the extra `socket()` calls.  Call `socket()` only once before entering the loop, and then have the loop call `connect()` for each IP using the existing `SOCKET` you already have.

**Edit** try something more like this:

```
std::string IP = "127.0.0.1";                 
std::string IP2 = "127.0.0.2";                 
std::string PORT = "1000";                 

void Connection(HWND hwnd) 
{ 
    std::string ip[2]; 
    ip[0] = IP;
    ip[1] = IP2;

    memset (&RemAdr, 0, sizeof(RemAdr));
    client = INVALID_SOCKET;

    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 0); 
    WSADATA wsaData; 

    if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) == 0) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            PHOSTENT hostinfo = gethostbyname(ip[i].c_str());
            if (hostinfo != NULL) 
                ip[i] = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)(hostinfo->h_addr_list[0])); 
        }

        client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
        if (client != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            RemAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            RemAdr.sin_port = htons(atoi(Port.c_str())); 

            do
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                {
                    RemAdr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip[i].c_str()); 

                    if (connect(client, (struct sockaddr *)&RemAdr, sizeof(RemAdr)) == 0) 
                    { 
                        WSAAsyncSelect(client, hwnd, RATMSG_SOCKET, FD_READ | FD_CLOSE | FD_CONNECT); 
                        return; 
                    }

                    Sleep(1000);
                }     
            }
            while (true); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it needs to be outside of the loop. Only the `connect()` should be inside the loop.

Comment: if onyl connect is inside the loop how would i change the ip it uses?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Was a simple mistake that you caught right away.

Comment: I'm having a problem. If the server side disconnects, this will try and reconnect. Problem is, it's not == 0 on the connect, and i Can't get it to return an error code. The server side accepts the connection attempt the second time but since it doesnt == 0 it wont go to WSAAsyncSelect

removing the secondary IP solves the problem but eh

Comment: `connect()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` if it fails.  You have to use `WSAGetLastError()` to get the actual error code.